How to use 'goto' in gopher-lua v1.1.0?
How to use 'goto' in gopher-lua v1.1.0? Is seems that gopher-lua has already support 'goto' over v1.1.0 link
I have already update gopher-lua's version in v1.1.0. But when I use goto goto and ::label:: statement like this
for i = 1, #backupSource do
    if i == 2 then
        goto continue
    end
    ::continue::
end

It get error
near '::':   syntax error

If someone could enlight me a bit that would be great :-) Thanks in advance

your problem is the ::continue:: is inside the loop try this.
for i = 1, #backupSource do
    if i == 2 then
        goto continue
    end 
end 
::continue::

Try and let me know
